# automatic undo for version control in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm not a mysql expert, but it seems like there is no obvious way to do that.
I'll explain what I want.
Let's say I'm doing a data migration which would update some rows in some table.

I'd like to be able to make a backup, execute migration script and get undo script automatically.

I don't see why this should be impossible, since rdbms stores all changes in a log already for transaction (mysql has `--log-bin` option for example) and they already know how to revert them (because they can rollback a transaction). So maybe it's possible to extract and use this data for the purpose of creating undo scripts for migrations?

EDIT.

Okay, so thanks to one of the answers I've found that mariadb actually partially support what I want already. This feature called [flashbacks](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/flashback/). It's actually doing what I've suggested - translating INSERTS into DELETE via binlog. So what I am missing is the upcoming support of flashbacks over DDL statements and making flashbacks only for one transaction.

Comment: As long as all operations are supported by transactions, I don't see a problem. Start a transaction, do migration. If something fails along the way, bailout and do a ROLLBACK. If everything is ok, COMMIT. If you dont want to build something of your own, there are open-source frameworks like https://flywaydb.org/ that can be of help

Comment: Migration should be tested. A lot of time can pass from the moment of applying of migration to the moment when it should be reverted.

Comment: Well then I think your out of luck. The world will unlikely be in the same state "now" as when you started the migration, so you can't construct an inverse to the migration.

Comment: DDL statements cannot be in transactions (until 8.0?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason RDBMS logs changes is crash recovery. Unless logical replication is set up, changes are usually stored in vendor specific format, not as series of sql statements.  Rolling transaction back involves restoring data to previous state, not generating and issuing another sql statement.  Generating such a statement for a random transaction appears to me as if not impossible ,but at least ambiguous and impractical. There is more than way to write "inverse" query, and this query will become invalid as soon as any new transaction commit.

For instance ,

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM table1;
ROLLBACK;
```

does not generate a bunch of `INSERT` statements. Most RDBMS will just not apply any changes to data files, so `ROLLBACK` will be executed immediately.

If you don't want to write sql scripts that undo effect of migration scripts, and your database doesn't support flashback (like Oracle or to some extent MariaDB) or Snapshot backups (like SQL Server) , there is no alternative to backup/restore.  You can reduce time of backup/restore to seconds even for huge databases by utilizing zfs filesystem or commercial products like NetApp

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to be able to make a backup, execute migration script and get undo script automatically.

Why?

If the migration fails so badly that it's going to be abandoned, then restore your backup of the database. 
That's the *only* way to *guarantee* that you'll get back to the point you started from.

I don't know of any way to create an "undo" script but, even if you could, there's no *guarantee* that it would work, potentially failing part way through its "recovery" and leaving you in an even *worse* position, somewhere between the last known Good State and the point where the migration failed but you won't be exactly sure *where*.  From then on, you're clutching at straws to try and clean up the mess.

Far better ( / easier / more reliable) to toss the "corrupted" database in the bin and restore it from the backup.

Comment: I'd agree. It's largely important to test the migration on dataset as close as possible to the one you're ultimately looking to change.

Comment: If creating undo scripts would be supported by database itself then there would guarantees that it would work. Restoring from backup is too long for large databases. We're talking here about version control for rdbms. Imagine git would use your approach and instead of storing only what's changed between vesrions it would store every version as a snapshot. It would be a disaster for performance.

Comment: @User1685095: "If creating undo scripts ... there would guarantees that it would work."  Not true.  After a failed migration, your transaction log [file] is full of committed but incorrect transactions.  Running an "Undo" script will generate yet more transaction logging.  If that transaction log file / disk fills up during the execution of your "Undo" script, your database dies.  Where's the "guarantee" in that? 

"Restoring from backup is too long".  Agreed; and that's why you *test* your migration as far as possible /before/ applying it to your real system.

Comment: @PhillW. You seem to be thinking that I want to do a migration and it's testing inside of one big transaction, which obviously wouldn't work in real world. At least I don't understand why are you talking about transaction log here. You say that migration need to be tested as far as possible. That's exactly what I'm saying and my question is about programmer productivity during this testing. Say I'm changing some static data in db and renaming some row value. When testing it I've found that I've maid a typo. I need to undo migration, fix typo and apply it again.

Comment: @PhillW. The only one way to automate it right now - restore from backup made just before transaction. Which in large database would require manually entering which tables you want to backup, because I can't make backups of all data every time I want to do a migration. I want to remove all unnecessary manual work here. What I want is to be able to say to the rdbms - "hey, I'm starting a transaction. You need to track all changes that would happen in this transaction and store them, so that I could undo them". Think about this as a kind of incremental snapshots. They exist in some rdbms.

Comment: @User1685095: Any RDBMS worth its salt will do all of that ...   right up to the point you execute a "commit".  If the migration process itself can programatically detect a failure, then it can rollback the entire transaction (i.e. the whole migration).  But, as soon as you send that commit statement, life gets complicated.  It seems that you're not [always] aware of what's being changed (worrying); perhaps the Migration process should start by taking copies of the tables that it intends to change.

Comment: I think I've already stated clearly, that I want to exclude manual labor here. I know how to accomplish this task with manual labor, backups etc. I'll accept @a1ex07 answer because he's actually answered my question. What I want is a little more advanced Point In Time Recovery mechanism.